# Clearing setTimeouts that are in conditional blocks

Tags: javascript

I have timeouts that only initialize when the page is scrolled a certain amount. The problem being that if I scroll to a page and don't wait for the timeout it continues to run into the next page. So I want to clear them when that page is no longer at that scroll offset. I found that you can only clear timeouts by storing them in a variable (ie: let x = setTimeout(func,time)) and then clearing the variable. But if I declare them inside the block statements the other blocks can't access it. But if I make it global it initializes without any condition. When I try encasing the global in a function so it doesn't execute right away (let x = ()=>{setTimeout(func,time)}), then I can no longer clear it for some reason.

```
contain.addEventListener("scroll",()=>{
// Frame 1
if(contain.scrollTop == 0){
    handleAudio2();
    handleAudio3();
    handleAudio4();
    emptyParticlesTwo();
    vid.pause();
}
if(contain.scrollTop == window.innerHeight){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        contain.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight)},23000)
}
if(contain.scrollTop == window.innerHeight*2){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        contain.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight)},23000)
}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the timeout id in a variable that is in a scope outside of the if statements. I would also recommend combining your two if statements, or putting an `else` before the second one. The way you have posted them here, the 2nd is redundant (it looks like it the 2nd 'if' shouldn't be in the timeout function)

```
var toID;
if(contain.scrollTop == window.innerHeight){
    toID = setTimeout(()=>{
        contain.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight)},23000)
}
if(contain.scrollTop == window.innerHeight*2){
    toID = setTimeout(()=>{
        contain.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight)},23000)
}})
```